# Azure Resource Manager: Restore VM from existing disk

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, azure-resource-manager

I have a storage account with as OS-disk blob and would like to redeploy the VM.
Under the classic deployment system I could simply choose from disk when creating a new VM, but I cant find that functionality on the new portal, it only offers the marketplace. The disk is in the new format so I cant use the classic portal.
Thanks

Comment: Unfortunately, you're down to either Powershell or Resource Templates to accomplish this - do you have a preference for either?

Comment: So you are required to redeploy your VM in Resource Manager mode?

Comment: Yeah, otherwise I cant access the storage drive.

Comment: Powershell is easier I guess...

Answer (score 3):

As noted in the comments, you can't do this end-to-end in the new portal yet.

Here's an Azure Resource Manager template to deploy a VM from an OS-disk blob: https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/tree/master/201-vm-specialized-vhd-new-or-existing-vnet
Using the "Deploy to Azure" button takes you to the new portal to enter parameters. The readme also includes PowerShell instructions.

This write-up also covers capturing an image, and links to some of the options for creating the image using different versions of PowerShell.. http://www.codeisahighway.com/how-to-capture-your-own-custom-virtual-machine-image-under-azure-resource-manager-api/

Comment: Thanks for calling this out @GertvandenBerg, updated the link.